# Unix Timestamp conversion for PHP Facebook event

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-php-sdk, unix-timestamp, iso8601

I am using the Facebook PHP SDK to post events to a page on their behalf, but I'm having some problems with the `start_time` param as I'm pulling the date from a form field. From what I understand this param only accepts an ISO 8601 format date, so I did the following...

The form field displays a date and time as follows (for example): `11/06/2013 08:00PM`

To which I convert it to a timestamp in Javascript by doing:

```
var d = new Date('11/06/2013 08:00PM'),
    eventTimestamp = d.getTime();
```

Which spits out `1383796800000` - converted back this timestamp in human-readable format is **Thu, 07 Nov 2013 04:00:00 GMT** *(11/6/2013 8:00:00 PM GMT-8 in my timezone...)*. So far so good!

Now here's where the problem comes in. I use POST to send this timestamp to my script posting the Facebook Event, and then to use it for the param I do this in PHP:

`date('c', $_POST['timestamp']);`

When I run the script the event that is posted comes out with a date of (as view on the Facebook Event page): **Saturday, November 25, 1995**.

I hope I described this well enough. Can someone please help me out here?

**Edit...**

I displayed the data returned by the timestamp in the script, and something interesting happened. Maybe I'm just missing something, but when I echoed `$_POST['timestamp']` I got:

`1383796800000` (correct)

But when I echoed `date('c', $_POST['timestamp'])` I got:

`1995-11-25T12:18:08-08:00` (very not correct)

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the value of `$_POST['timestamp']` same as the one you supposedly posted?

Comment: I edited my post above to check the values, and you were right, they're not the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I've over looked something, the date range for date() is "Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT" and your timestamp is higher then this range.

Edit...

You need to divide it by `1000`

```
date('c' $_POST['timestamp']/1000);
```

which will return `2013-11-06T21:00:00-07:00`

Comment: Okay, weird.. when I convert the timestamp using http://epochconverter.com I get `Thu, 07 Nov 2013 04:00:00 GMT`, but when I convert it using http://onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm I get `Tue, 10 Oct 45820 16:00:00 GMT`, and when I use http://4webhelp.net/us/timestamp.php I get `Friday, July 4th 2408, 16:00:00 (GMT)`... why are all three sites giving me different answers?

Comment: Could my timestamp be corrupt? If it is, how come the one site gives me the date I expect? Also, following my method above, how could it be corrupt?

Comment: Im new to the site and didn't mean post my reply as an answer but i figured it out and have updated my answer above.

Comment: Booyah! It worked! Now, for the sake of the community and anyone who has the same question as me, exactly *why* did I need to divide by 1000?